# Getting the message: "Ensure the instance is running on an AMI that supports EC2 Instance Connect"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am getting below issue while connecting EC2 instance:

> There was a problem connecting to your instance
> Log in failed. If this instance has just started up, wait a few minutes and try again. Otherwise, ensure the instance is running on an AMI that supports EC2 Instance Connect.

Any suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: You can connect to it through session manager or standalone ssh client and check the status of instance connect. If not installed, you can install it manually. Also as @Caldazar suggested, you need to have a public ip for the instance.

Comment: If you are trying to connect via _EC2 Instance Connect_, you also need to open SSH (port 22) to the range of IP addresses used by EC2 Instance Connect (rather than your own IP address). You can test whether this is the cause of the problem by temporarily opening port 22 to `0.0.0.0/0`. The instance also needs to be in a Public Subnet with a public IP address.

Answer (score 1):

EC2 instance connect is supported on Amazon Linux 2 and Ubuntu 16.04+ per [Instance connect documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-connect-methods.html) so if your AMI is for one of those, it's supported.

Also, you should check if you have a public IPv4 address for that instance